# How to add class to buttons on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Sorry for silly question , but I can't add class to button on click. I have list of buttons and on click I need to change background of active button . I dont know how to get index of element on click inside list and add class.  I need to make it on pure javascript. Only need to leave  `$(document).ready(function()` . Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/armakarma/ns5tfcL0/15/

HTML

```
<div class="content-itinerary__buttons-wrapper">
    <button class="content-itinerary__buttons description-text ">Day 2</button>
    <button class="content-itinerary__buttons description-text">Day 3</button>
    <button class="content-itinerary__buttons description-text">Day 4</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
let myBtns=document.querySelector('.content-itinerary__buttons-wrapper')

  myBtns.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    console.log('test')
  }) 
});
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList, you cannot call `addEventListener` on that like in jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/4gd2m1rb/

Comment: @freefaller I need keep background active

Comment: you are adding the click event to the wrapper and not the initial buttons itself.. why?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hc3gnw9s/

Comment: @YerlanYeszhanov Check my updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/4gd2m1rb/

Comment: hii @Yerlan Yeszhanov check below update code and vote up...☺

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Only need to leave `$(document).ready(function()`*

I am not sure why do you need to leave that when you have the equivalent JavaScript ([`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event)).

Loop through all the buttons, inside the event handler function first remove the *class* from all the buttons then add the *class* only to the clicked button:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    let myBtns=document.querySelectorAll('.content-itinerary__buttons');
    myBtns.forEach(function(btn) {

        btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
          myBtns.forEach(b => b.classList.remove('active'));
          btn.classList.add('active');
        });
 
    });

});
```

```css
.active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-itinerary__buttons-wrapper">

  <button class="content-itinerary__buttons description-text ">Day 2</button>
  <button class="content-itinerary__buttons description-text">Day 3</button>
  <button class="content-itinerary__buttons description-text">Day 4</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to use `event` object in `click` event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let myBtns=document.querySelectorAll('.content-itinerary__buttons-wrapper')[0];

  myBtns.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
    if (e.target.className.indexOf('clicked') === -1) {
      e.target.className += ' clicked';
    } else {
      e.target.className = e.target.className.replace(' clicked', '');
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: OP wants to add the event to every button, not just the first.

Comment: We add ```click``` event listener on wrapper of buttons. So we don't need to add ```click``` event listener for each button inside it

Comment: @TienDuong after clicking on another element , "clicked" class  does not removes from previous element

Comment: @YerlanYeszhanov I added the condition to only add "clicked" only once

Comment: @YerlanYeszhanov I edited my code to toggle "clicked" class

Answer (score 2):

This is your solution

```js
var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("content-itinerary__buttons");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
  this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
.content-itinerary__buttons-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.content-itinerary__buttons {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 21px 15px 15px 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #D7D7D7;
    outline: none;

    &:not(:last-child) {
        border-right: 0;
    }

}

.active, .btn:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-itinerary__buttons-wrapper" id="myDIV">
     <button  class="content-itinerary__buttons description-text active ">Day 2</button>
     <button class="content-itinerary__buttons description-text">Day 3</button>
     <button class="content-itinerary__buttons description-text ">Day 4</button>
     <button class="content-itinerary__buttons description-text">Day 5</button>
     <button class="content-itinerary__buttons description-text">Day 6</button>
     <button class="content-itinerary__buttons description-text">Day 7</button>
     <button class="content-itinerary__buttons description-text">Day 8</button>
     <button class="content-itinerary__buttons description-text">Day 9</button>
     <button class="content-itinerary__buttons description-text">Day 10</button>
</div>
```

See Code [link](https://jsfiddle.net/m35oh1x9/)

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely use [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) API for adding/removing classes to/from elements.

**Why?**

- Adding/removing classes won't affect other classes already set to the element
- Updating the `className` of the element will replace all existing classes
- It comes with handy functions like "toggle" and "replace

Your code will look something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
let myBtns=document.querySelectorAll('.content-itinerary__buttons-wrapper')

  myBtns
    .forEach(btn => btn
        .addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        // Check if the classList already exists on the element clicked
        // If so, remove it
        // Else, add it
            e.classList.contains('clicked') 
                ? e.classList.add('clicked') 
                : e.classList.remove('clicked');
        })
    ); 
});
```

Comment: You need to beware that IE doesn't support classList well.

Comment: That's not entirely true. Both IE 10 & 11 provide partial support  for `classList`. See https://caniuse.com/#search=classList. So you have to be aware of this if you want to use it in combination with older browsers like IE 10 & 11.

Comment: IE 10 & 11 support classList but it doesn't support add, remove, toggle, replace function of classList just check on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 1):

Onclick of the button you can set class name to the button

```js
function a(e)
{
e.setAttribute("class","active");
}
```

```css
.active
{
color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-itinerary__buttons-wrapper">
    <button class="content-itinerary__buttons description-text" onclick="a(this)">Day </button>
    <button class="content-itinerary__buttons description-text" onclick="a(this)">Day </button>
    <button class="content-itinerary__buttons description-text" onclick="a(this)">Day </button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you going to get rid of jQuery replace wrapper function to use listen for `DOMContentLoaded` event. It's the same as jQuery `documentReady`.

In your click handler use `event` object, `ev.target` in my example is a button which fired the event. Then use classList property to add  your class.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
let myBtns=document.querySelector('.content-itinerary__buttons-wrapper')

  myBtns.addEventListener('click', (ev)=>{
    let btn = ev.target;
    btn.classList.add('red');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use forEach loop :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 let myBtns=document.querySelectorAll('.content-itinerary__buttons-wrapper')

 let myAllButtons = myBtns.querySelectorAll('.content-itinerary__buttons')

 myAllButtons.forEach(function(element) {
    element.onclick = () => element.classList.add('some-class')
 })
});
```

Comment: Sorry man, firstly I didn't understand your questiyon, take it