# How to single select button using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can I manipulate CSS and read text value and save it into variable when clicking on the button. when I click on the button using jquery how can I add a CSS to the button such as `class="btn-n-active"`.

How to make sure that only one button is selected while switching on different buttons and that button should have `active` CSS

I was trying to just read the single value from the options, just a single selection.

```
<p> 
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn-n">DOG</button>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn-n">CAT</button>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn-n">LION</button>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn-n">PIG</button>
</p>
```

```
const myFunction = () => {

}
```

It's like a quiz system where I just want to read a single value. I am not able to apply the logic

Comment: so...what have you tried so far ? this a pretty simple task. I am sure you will find your answer here on SO somewhere

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add class to buttons on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57143671/how-to-add-class-to-buttons-on-click)

Comment: Hi @Mihai i am not able to apply logic so that I can select the only a single value and add CSS class to it

Comment: well. you need to adapt it a little bit. there are questions about that too. you just have to 'ask' SO and it will help you out. At least post something you have tried. Show us some effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of options to do this. Below you will see 3 of them.

The idea is to select all buttons and remove the active class and then add it to the button you clicked on.

My jquery is a bit rusty but I suggest you use just javaScript for such a simple request

```js
const myFunction = (event) => {
  const clickedElem = event.target
  const allBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-n')
  allBtns.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove("btn-n-active"))
  clickedElem.classList.add("btn-n-active")

}

// option 2 without adding function in html


/*  const allBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-n')
 allBtns.forEach(btn => btn.onclick = () => {
      allBtns.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove("btn-n-active"))
       btn.classList.add("btn-n-active")
      
 }) */

//option3 simple jQuery

/* const allBtns = $('.btn-n');
allBtns.click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("btn-n-active")
  allBtns.not(this).removeClass("btn-n-active")
}) */

const submit = () => {
  const selectedText = document.querySelector(".btn-n-active") ? document.querySelector(".btn-n-active").innerText : 'Please select one'
  console.log(selectedText)
}
```

```css
.btn-n-active {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> 
  <button onclick="myFunction(event)" class="btn-n">DOG</button>
  <button onclick="myFunction(event)" class="btn-n">CAT</button>
  <button onclick="myFunction(event)" class="btn-n">LION</button>
  <button onclick="myFunction(event)" class="btn-n">PIG</button>
</p>
<button onclick="submit()">Click to see selected text</button>
```

Comment: I was going through the first approach if i have class with spaces than it throws error ```<button onclick="myFunction(event)" class="btn n">DOG</button>```

Comment: that's not A class with spaces. Those are two classes. `btn` and `n`.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the selected answer button having the active class using the hasClass('btn-n-active')

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("button").removeClass("btn-n-active"); // Remove other active class
    $(this).addClass("btn-n-active"); // Add active class to the clicked button
});


const myFunction = () => {
    var selectedButtonText = $("button").hasClass("btn-n-active").html();
    console.log("Selected answer: " + selectedButtonText);
}
```